# How to Use front camera in TedPicker Library

Tags: android

I am using this library.
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3092
Everything works well.
I just want to know what changes do i need to make it use front camera !

Answer (score 0):

`TedPicker` library uses [CWAC-CAMERA](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/README-original.markdown) to take pictures, so you can read here about how to implement front camera by implementing `SimpleCameraHost` and overriding `useFrontFacingCamera()`. For more info you can keep reading their markdown: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/blob/master/README-original.markdown

Comment: have you succeeded @denis_lor ?